# Sticky notes Windows 7 x64 searching issue

Tags: sticky-notes

The index service is not indexing the text within the sticky notes. I have plenty of notes but when I search with the search connector-Microsoft I do not get any results, even if I know that this word I am searching for, exists in the notes.

Any help?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but one possible way: start --> type index --> click index options. Click advanced --> filetype --> add --> add .snt filetype --> Click "index properties and file contents --> OK --> close ...give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Click *Start* → Type `index` → Click on *Indexing options* → *Modify* → In *Change Selected Locations* uncheck the *Windows Sticky Notes* and click *OK*.

Then click again on *Modify* and recheck the *Windows Sticky Notes*.

It is not a permanent solution, but all notes made to this moment will be indexed. Repeating this procedure once in a while you will have all notes indexed. Let me know if you found another solution.